# Various types of multimode fibers

Tags: optical-fibre

I have recently been studying fibers in school. I know there are 2 main types of fibers, singlemode and multimode. I know that single-modal are the most used for long journeys and because they have a lower cost than multimodal ones. Multimodals are divided into 2 types: step-index and graded-index. I have studied that graded-indexes with respect to step-indexes solve the problem of modal dispersion. Is this the only difference? I searched various sites but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why are you looking to see if there are other differences? There are, but are you looking for an encyclopediac discussion such as might be found on Wikipedia? Or is there a goal here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.